# More than one start on one Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Iam trying to start a thread more than one time. But I read that is not possible, because I get a the IllegalThreadStateException for it. Iam trying to do the following thing. I have **n** smartphone. I would like to do an automatic test on apps. the tests are parallel, one app per device.  any idea to solve it? Here is my Code?

```
Semaphore smartphones = new Semaphore(androidComponents.size());
Thread evaluationProcess = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                smartphones.acquire();
                [CODE FOR TESTING]
                smartphones.release();
        }
    };

    while (!evaluationCompleted(apps)) {
        evaluationProcess.start();
        while (smartphones.availablePermits() == 0) ;
    }
```

Comment: You're trying to start a thread that is already running. That won't work by definition. Maybe you're confusing the Thread class or object with the thread concept?

Comment: Well, create one Runnable instance, and several Thread instances from this Runnable instance. Also, don't use busy-loops to wait for something to happen.

Comment: A pool of Executors should be preferred to using bare Threads.  There's a reason for the new concurrency package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget starting your own thread or threads and orchestrating them with your own semaphores. This constitutes a) overengineering, and b) not using the right tools for the job.

The threads can be managed by a threadpool, and all the semaphores can be replaced with a single concurrent (thread-safe) queue.

With a threadpool you can run methods known as "runners". You could create a new runner whenever you need a new one, but it is easier to just reuse an existing runner simply by making it run in a loop. The trick is that in each iteration of the loop, the runner picks the next item to work on from the queue and processes it.

So, in your example, you stuff all of your smartphones in a queue, and then each "runner" waits until a smartphone is available to dequeue, dequeues it, performs the test, and repeats. The implementation of the concurrent blocking queue guarantees that it will share its contents fairly between consumers.

If you have N runners and you want them to gracefully stop, enqueue N instances of a special sentinel value which means "please quit". When a runner sees this special value, it quits. This will cause exactly N runners to quit.

Read up on `java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue` and on `ThreadPoolExecutor`, they are the tool to use for the job.

Comment: And a thread pool takes care of thread bookkeeping, and handles joining the threads when you shut down the pool. Additionally, a fixed-size thread pool would make the OP's semaphore unnecessary, inasmuch as its purpose seems to be simply to cap the number of threads running concurrently.  I'm not necessarily against doing one's own thread management, but this case seems very well suited to using a pool, instead.

Answer (score 3):

Because you cannot call start on a thread twice.

[Thread API:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start())

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a
>   thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.

You must put in run() a *unit of work* - the code that needs to be executed by multiple threads. And then instantiate as many threads as you need (calling start on each, but only once).

Answer (score 1):

Extract your Thread implementation into its own class, instantiate some instances of those, and start them one-by-one. Example:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       // Do some cool stuff here!
    }
}
```

... And then, elsewhere in your code, when you want to start multiple "copies" of your thread...

```
public void startThreads() {
    MyThread threadA = new MyThread(),
             threadB = new MyThread(),
             threadC = new MyThread();
    threadA.start();
    threadB.start();
    threadC.start();
    // make as many as you need, then invoke start on them.
}
```

BUT, as others have already pointed out, each instance of Thread can only be `start()`ed one time.